# php: check if certain item in an array is empty

Tags: php, arrays

In PHP, how would one check to see if a specified item (by name, I think - number would probably also work) in an array is empty?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Types of empty (from PHP Manual). The following are considered empty for any variable:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)

So take the example below:

```
$arr = array(
          'ele1' => 'test',
          'ele2' => false           
       );
```

1) $arr['ele3'] is not set. So:
`isset($arr['ele3']) === false && empty($arr['ele3']) === true`
it is not set and empty. empty() checks for whether the variable is set and empty or not.

2) $arr['ele2'] is set, but empty. So:
`isset($arr['ele2']) === true && empty($arr['ele2']) === true`

1) $arr['ele1'] is set and not empty:
`isset($arr['ele1']) === true && empty($arr['ele1']) === false`

if you wish to check whether is it empty, simply use the empty() function.

Comment: Oooh, helpful. I would upvote you guys if I had enough rep. Heh.

Answer (score 16):

```
if(empty($array['item']))
```

or

```
if(!isset($array['item']))
```

or

```
if(!array_key_exists('item', $array))
```

depending on what *precisely* you mean by "empty".  See the docs for [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)  and [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) as to what exactly they mean.

Comment: OK. What kinds of empty are there?

Comment: Addendum: I think the item(s) I'm dealing with look like => '',
What would that be?

Comment: That will be empty, set, and existant.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$myarray=array(1,5,6,5);

$anotherarray=array();

function checkEmpty($array){  
return (count($array)>0)?1:0;  
  }
echo checkEmpty($myarray);

echo checkEmpty($anotherarray);

?>
```

(for checking if empty result 1 else 0);

Compactness is what I persue in my code.

Answer (score 0):

i had such situation where i was getting tab it last index of array  so if put things together then this might work for the most of cases

```
<?php 

if( ctype_space($array['index'])  && empty($array['index'])  && !isset($array['index']) ){
   echo 'array index is empty';
}else{
  echo 'Not empty';
}
```