# Empty Array won't be "empty"

Tags: php, arrays

I got an array, filled with things out of a MySQL. Sometimes there isn't any data, so I tried checking with `empty()` to see if I should drop the emtpy array or if it contains any data. I tried it with an empty array but `empty()` gives me a "full" array, even if `print_r` shows an empty.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( ) ) )
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( ) ) )
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask...

Comment: If you want this problem to be solved, you're going to have to show a little more code of what you are doing...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616603/php-check-if-certain-item-in-an-array-is-empty

Comment: If anything else, it's even less clear.  I have absolutely no idea what you think you're trying to ask, much less what you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 2):

`empty()` will return true for array(), FALSE, NULL, '', 0, and '0'. An empty array would be empty(), but an array *containing* an empty array would not.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $array is the array in your example, try this:

```
$array = array_filter( $array );
if ( empty( $array ) )
{
    // do what you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do what I *think* you're trying to do, you need to write a recursive function that will traverse through every item in every level of your multidimensional array and check the empty() value of every element. I think this is what you're after.

```
function isEmpty($array){
    $empty = true;
    foreach($array as $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            if(!isEmpty($value)) $empty = false;
        }else{
            if(!empty($value)) $empty = false;
        }
    }
    return $empty;
}
```

Then just run isEmpty() on your array.

Answer (score 0):

I believe BraedenP is correct.

However, a far superior solution is to make changes *in the place where you create that array*. In that context, it should be really easy to detect whether the number of rows in the SQL resultset is `0`.