# How to insert multiple rows of student records scores in a while loop in a database table?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to create a table with input fields where student records can be inserted. The name of the students are in the first column of the table fetched from the database with a while loop. The other columns contain fields for inputing the student scores. The challenge I'm facing is how to insert the records of all the students in different row of a table called result_sec into the database. I've search for similar post but couldn't get a suitable answer. Below is the code. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php require('header.php'); ?>
<?php 
$query_form = sprintf("SELECT * FROM regform LIMIT 2");
$form = mysqli_query($conn, $query_form) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$formdata = mysqli_fetch_assoc($form);

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$exes = $_POST['exe'];
$asss = $_POST['ass'];
$ca1s = $_POST['ca1'];
$ca2s = $_POST['ca2'];
$exams = $_POST['exam'];

    foreach($exes as $key => $exe)
    {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO result_sec (exe, ass, ca1, ca2, exam) VALUES ('$exe', '$asss[$key]', '$ca1s[$key]', '$ca2s[$key]', '$exams[$key]')";
    }
    $insert = mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql);
}
?>
<form method="POST">
    <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Ass.</th>
        <th>Exe.</th>        
        <th>1st C.A.</th>
        <th>2nd C.A.</th>
        <th>Exam</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
     <?php do { ?> 
      <tr>
          <td><?php echo $formdata['surname']." ".$formdata['firstname']; ?></td>
          <td><input name="ass[]" size="1px"/></td>
          <td><input name="exe[]" size="1px" /></td>
          <td><input name="ca1[]" size="1px" /></td>
          <td><input name="ca2[]" size="1px" /></td>
          <td><input name="exam[]" size="1px" /></td>
          <input type="hidden" name="regformid[]" value="<?php echo $formdata['regformid'];?>" />
      </tr>
     <?php } while ($formdata = mysqli_fetch_assoc($form)); ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Insert Student Record</button>
    </form>
<?php require('footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Why are you using a loop instead of a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See If this resolve your problem

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $exes = $_POST['exe'];
    $asss = $_POST['ass'];
    $ca1s = $_POST['ca1'];
    $ca2s = $_POST['ca2'];
    $exams = $_POST['exam'];

    //You can use a foreach loop to loop over one of the repeated inputs, and then use the index to access the corresponding elements in the others:
    foreach ($exes as $i => $exe) {
        $exee = mysqli_real_escape_string($exe);
        $ass = mysqli_real_escape_string($asss[$i]);
        $ca1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($ca1s[$i]);
        $ca2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($ca2s[$i]);
        $exam = mysqli_real_escape_string($exams[$i]);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO result_sec (exe, ass, ca1, ca2, exam) 
            VALUES ('$exee', '$ass', '$ca1', '$ca2', '$exam')";
            $insert = mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to include a name in the  submit button. It worked as I wanted it too... Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Please is there a way I can check if any of the fields in the array is empty? So that I can avoid inserting empty fields into the database.

Comment: See if this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616603/php-check-if-certain-item-in-an-array-is-empty

Comment: I already tried something similar but did not work [link](stackoverflow.com/questions/6621683/how-to-check-if-an-array-contains-empty-elements)
`function testEmpty($array) {
  foreach ($array as $element) {
    if (empty($element))
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

if(testEmpty($studentid) == true)
{
 //Insert scores into the databse 
}` It did not insert into the database at all even if there is no empty fields @Shehary